# How do I find the percentile of a distribution with information only about mean, variance, skewness and kurtosis?

Tags: statistics, percentile

e.g., if my data distribution has 4 points, with a mean of 5, skewness 13, kurtosis 220 and variance 11, how do I find the 75th percentile?

Or is this example a very special case?

Answer (score 1):

Kurtosis $K$ is [bounded below](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kurtosis#Pearson_moments) by skewness $S$:
$$
K\ge S^2+1
$$

Your data suggests that $S^2+1 = 270 > K=220$. No wonder that Adrian couldn't solve the problem with Mathematica.

Answer (score 0):

**This is a partial answer.**

The four values there give you four equations which you might be able to solve for the data points. That is, you have
\begin{align*}
\frac14\left[a+b+c+d\right]&=5\\
\frac14\left[(a-5)^2+(b-5)^2+(c-5)^2+(d-5)^2\right]&=11 \\
\frac{\frac14\left[(a-5)^3+(b-5)^3+(c-5)^3+(d-5)^3\right]}{\left(\sqrt{11}\right)^3}&=13 \\
\frac{\frac14\left[(a-5)^4+(b-5)^4+(c-5)^4+(d-5)^4\right]}{\left(\sqrt{11}\right)^4}&=220 .
\end{align*}
There's definitely a pattern to these equations. Let
\begin{align*}
e&=a-5\\
f&=b-5\\
g&=c-5\\
h&=d-5.
\end{align*}
Then the four equations become
\begin{align*}
e+f+g+h&=0\\
e^2+f^2+g^2+h^2&=44\\
e^3+f^3+g^3+h^3&=52\cdot 11^{3/2}\\
e^4+f^4+g^4+h^4&=106480.
\end{align*}
We can solve the first to eliminate $e,$ which yields the system
\begin{align*}
(-f-g-h)^2+f^2+g^2+h^2&=44\\
(-f-g-h)^3+f^3+g^3+h^3&=52\cdot 11^{3/2}\\
(-f-g-h)^4+f^4+g^4+h^4&=106480.
\end{align*}

This is the point where I would hand it off to Mathematica. Unfortunately, Mathematica only finds solutions which have some complex numbers - I'm assuming that doesn't make sense for your application. I had hoped that Mathematica would find a solution with all real numbers. Then to find the $75$th percentile, you would simply take the average of the two highest numbers. But without real solutions to this system, we're kind of dead in the water.